# Problem with assigning a returned promise item to a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

So i just want to assign a returned promise element to a variable `msg` without having to do this:

```js
let msg = null; 
page.$('title').then(elem => {
    msg = elem.text();
});
```

**Code explanation**: Here im just using puppeteer to select an element, which is then returned; I then want to assign the returned element's text to the msg variable.

My question here is "Is it possible to simplify this expression and do something that resembles to this code below?"

```js
let msg = page.$('title').then(elem => {elem.text()});
```

**PS**: I know this is not valid code, I'm just trying to represent my goal :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `async await` to simplify your code.

```js
const message = (await page.$('title')).text();
```

Code should run as an async function.

Comment: Also would there be a method with the es6 syntax?

Comment: @Alex For ES6 there is no better alternative than `then`. But you can use babel use new features of newer ES versions and target ES6 aswell.

Comment: Oh so @Eldar if I want to use the es6 version I'll have to do it like this `let msg = null; page.$('title').then(elem => { msg = elem.text();});` ?

Comment: @Alex actually just assigning `msg` is not enough. You need to move your code that manipulates `msg` variable into `then` callback. Otherwise you will get undefined errors.